# Inner product of function of period $2\pi$ with exponential

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous with period $2\pi$. Prove that $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^Nf\left(\dfrac{2\pi j}{N}\right)e^{-2\pi ijn/N}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx.$$

The right-hand side is the inner product $\langle f,e^{inx}\rangle$. What can we use to relate it to the left-hand side?

Comment: That's a [Riemann sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum).

Comment: @Lucian Of course, you're right! The question then becomes, why it converges to the right-hand side.

Comment: By a simple change in variable, $2\pi t\to x$, where $t=\frac jN$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)e^{-inx}$. Multiply both sides by $2\pi$. The statement becomes
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{2\pi}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N g\left(\dfrac{2\pi j}{N}\right) = \int_0^{2\pi}g(x) dx
$$
which comes straight out of the definition of Riemann integral. The function $g$ is Riemann integrable because it's continuous.

The periodicity of $f$ does not matter.